# Host an API on Heroku using a manual docker build

Tags: docker, heroku, fastapi, uvicorn

I want to host a small web app on the Heroku free tier. I'm using `docker compose` to run the frontend, backend api, and a postgres DB locally. I am following the Heroku docs on [deploying an existing docker image](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime#pushing-an-existing-image). However, when I try access the API docs, or try curl the API (both of which work locally), I get the error

```
2021-01-31T15:19:23.679917+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/docs" host=apitest48398.herokuapp.com request_id=62ffd495-5977-4132-9ec7-d89abf5b1d8f fwd="77.100.21.140" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-01-31T15:19:24.465326+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=apitest48398.herokuapp.com request_id=016de415-dc8e-4b0a-894e-8fad37ff7fee fwd="77.100.21.140" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Note I am deploying via the container registry, not by connecting my git repo to Heroku, hence neither a `Procfile`, nor a `heroku.yml` file.

Here are the steps to reproduce this behaviour in a minimal example. Note that in the real example, I have multiple docker files, so even though this simple example could have been deployed using `heroku container:push`, I prefer to build the images myself so the simple example is more representative of the real use case:

1. Create the app using `fastAPI` in a file called `main.py`:

   ```py
   from fastapi import FastAPI

   app = FastAPI()


   @app.get("/")
   async def root():
       return {"message": "Hello World"}
   ```
2. Create a `requirements.txt` file:

   ```
   fastapi
   uvicorn
   ```
3. Create the `Dockerfile`:

   ```
   FROM python:3.7

   ENV PORT=$PORT

   COPY ./requirements.txt .
   RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

   COPY ./main.py .

   EXPOSE $PORT

   CMD uvicorn main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port $PORT
   ```
4. build the image

   ```sh
   docker build . -t herokubackendtest
   ```
5. log in to heroku

   ```
   heroku container:login
   ```
6. Create the heroku app and push the image to heroku (you'd need to use a different, unique APP_NAME)

   ```sh
   export APP_NAME=apitest48398
   heroku create $APP_NAME
   docker tag herokubackendtest registry.heroku.com/$APP_NAME/api
   docker push registry.heroku.com/$APP_NAME/api
   ```
7. Release the app, scale up a dyno, check that the process is running, and check the logs to verify the `uvicorn` is running:

   ```sh
   heroku container:release --app $APP_NAME api
   heroku ps:scale --app $APP_NAME api=1
   heroku ps --app $APP_NAME  # should show === api (Free): /bin/sh -c uvicorn\ main:app\ --host\ 0.0.0.0\ --port\ \$PORT (1)
   heroku logs --app $APP_NAME --tail
   ```

You should see the following in the logs (the port number will vary)

```
2021-01-31T15:17:39.806481+00:00 heroku[api.1]: Starting process with command `/bin/sh -c uvicorn\ main:app\ --host\ 0.0.0.0\ --port\ \16384`
2021-01-31T15:17:40.465132+00:00 heroku[api.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-01-31T15:17:41.982857+00:00 app[api.1]: INFO:     Started server process [5]
2021-01-31T15:17:41.982918+00:00 app[api.1]: INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
2021-01-31T15:17:41.983162+00:00 app[api.1]: INFO:     Application startup complete.
2021-01-31T15:17:41.983529+00:00 app[api.1]: INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://0.0.0.0:16384 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

Now to test it, you should be able to see the openAPI (swagger) docs at `https://apitest48398.herokuapp.com/docs` where `apitest48398` is your `$APP_NAME`. But instead I get the error in the logs I posted at the start of this question, and I see a page that says:

```
Application error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details. You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command
heroku logs --tail
```

in my browser.

I also would expect `curl https://apitest48398.herokuapp.com/` to return my `hello world` json, but it instead returns some HTML with an error. I've also tried with ports `443`, `80`, and the port uvicorn is running on inside the container (this one just hangs until timeout).

I assume I have missed some step, maybe with SSL? Although I understood that this was automatically enabled for any herokuapp.com domains on the free tier, and I can't see any way to pass the cert and pem files through to uvicorn.

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to how to resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tag the image using the `web` process type, as indicated by [Heroku Docker Registry](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime). In your case

```
docker tag herokubackendtest registry.heroku.com/$APP_NAME/web
docker push registry.heroku.com/$APP_NAME/web
heroku container:release web --app $APP_NAME
```

Comment: omg, I can't believe that's all it was. Even from your link, it is not at all clear to me that the process type needed to have the specific name `web`, lol. I thought it was just a name you could pick. So does that imply that if I have both a front end webpage, and a backend api service, I need to make them separate heroku apps, since they both need to be called web?

Comment: web is the process-type which means it will accept HTTP requests (unlike workers that work in background). You need 2 web dynos if your frontend call the backend via HTTP

Comment: Can you have 2 web dynos in a single heroku app? I assumed not based on the code in your answer as there would be no way to distinguish them. Does 2 web dynos mean two heroku apps, each with a web dyno?

Comment: yes, sorry for the confusion. One app needs one dyno. If you package frontend and backend in one app then one web dyno is what you need.